# Changes lost while rebasing and accidentally switching to different branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

On branch `foo` I started a rebase like this: `git rebase --interactive HEAD~1`, where I wanted to add changes for last commit in file `A`.

I made my changes, `git add` them, and then `git commit --amend` them. (Please note that I have not issued `git rebase --continue` command yet)

Then I switched to branch `bar` via `git checkout bar`; did nothing there and switched back to `foo` via `git checkout foo`. When checking file `A`, I found that all changes I did during rebase were gone, even though `git status` says:

```
Last command done (1 command done):
   e deadbee Nice commit message
```

Is it possible to get those changes back?

Comment: is the repo publicly hosted anywhere like github?

Comment: maybe `git rebase --abort`

Comment: @hellyale no, it's not. Even if it was, how could that help?

Comment: @mb21 why do I want to `abort` my rebase and lose all changes I did during the rebase? If it was the case, I could just `git rebase --continue` and nothing would have changed. I state in the question that I already lost my changes I did during rebase and is it possible to get them back.

Comment: @Mikhail can see the history tree using `/network` and visually identify if the commit is still in the history tree. If it is, you can get it back, if it isn't it is gone.

Comment: @hellyale I am afraid I do not understand what you want to do. No commits are gone, all commits are there; I am inside rebase currently. The only thing that's gone is *changes* I did during the rebase after I switch branches forth and back. Could you please re-read the question to make sure we are on the same page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start an interactive rebase, Git puts you in "detached HEAD" mode.  When you check out a branch name by name, Git puts you in "attached HEAD" mode, i.e., back on a branch.  This rather badly disrupts an ongoing rebase, because any new commits you made are now difficult to find.

[Lemuel Nabong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50237092/1256452) contains the key (but is wrong): you must re-check-out the appropriate detached-HEAD commit, which you can find using `git reflog`.  Don't do this with `git reset`, do it with `git checkout hash` or `git checkout HEAD@{number}`, after finding the correct commit in the reflog.  You should then be able to continue your rebase.

#### Long description

What *detached HEAD* means here is that the special file `.git/HEAD` (which always exists) no longer contains *the name of a branch*.  Normally `HEAD`, or `.git/HEAD`, contains a string like `ref: refs/heads/master` to indicate that the current branch is the one named `master`.  The current branch then determines the current commit.

For doing certain kinds of work, though—including interactive rebase—Git changes `.git/HEAD` so that it contains instead a raw commit hash ID.  The interesting thing about this mode is that you can make new commits, which get new hash IDs that are different from every existing commit.  When you do this, those new commits' IDs can *only* by found by reading `.git/HEAD` itself.

A picture, I think, makes this a lot clearer.  If we start with a tiny repository with just three commits in it, we can draw them like this, using single uppercase letters to stand in for those horrible hash ID strings like `ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c`.  We'll call our first commit `A`, our second `B`, and our third `C`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

Commit `C`, our latest commit, has its hash ID stored under the name `master`.  We say that the name `master` *points to* `C`.  Commit `C` itself stores the hash ID of commit `B` as its *parent*, so we say that `C` points to `B`.  Commit `B` stores `A`'s hash ID in turn, so `B` points to `A`.  Commit `A` is the very first commit ever made, so it has no parent at all.  Git calls this a *root commit*, and it's where the action stops if we run `git log`, for instance, because there's no earlier commits to look at.

Hence, Git always works *backwards:* a branch name points to the *last* commit on the branch.  The commit itself remembers the previous commit, and so on.  If we go to add a *new* commit to `master`, we run:

```
git checkout master   # if needed
... do things to modify files ...
git add file1 file2 ...
git commit
```

The commit step packages up the latest snapshot (from the *index* aka *staging area*, where `git add` copied them, but we'll leave that for another topic), then writes out a new commit `D` whose parent is the current commit `C`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
         \
          D
```

Finally, having written out the new commit, `git commit` writes the new commit's hash ID—whatever it turns out to be; it's not easily predicted—into the name `master` so that `master` now points to `D`:

```
A <-B <-C
         \
          D   <--master
```

and the commit is done.

The way that Git knows *which* branch name to update, if you have more than one branch name, is by attaching `HEAD` to it.  Suppose that instead of committing `D` on `master`, we do this:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b develop    # create new develop branch
```

Now the drawing looks like this (I'm dropping the internal arrows, we know they always point backwards and they get hard to draw):

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

We do our work, `git add`, and `git commit`, and since `HEAD` is attached to `develop` rather than `master`, Git writes new commit `D`'s hash ID into `develop` rather than `master`, giving:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

A *detached HEAD* just means that instead of having `HEAD` attached to some branch name, `HEAD` points directly to some commit.  If we detached `HEAD` now and had it point to commit `D`, we could draw this as:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop, HEAD
```

If we now make a *new* commit `E`, we'll get this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop
         \
          E   <-- HEAD
```

If we now say `git checkout master`, this is what happens:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- develop
         \
          E   <-- ???
```

The way to get back to where we were is to find some name for commit `E` (remember, its real name is some big ugly hash ID).

Both rebase and `git commit --amend` work by making *new* commits.  The special thing that `--amend` does is to make the new commit with its parent being the current commit's *parent*.  If we start with:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and run `git commit --amend`, Git makes a new commit `E` whose parent is `D`'s parent `C`, rather than `D` itself.  Git then writes that into the appropriate name—`develop` in this case—giving:

```
        E   <-- develop (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- ??? [abandoned?]
```

#### This is where reflogs come in

Each branch name has a reflog, recording the commit IDs that the branch name *used to* point-to.  That is, if `master` pointed to `A` at one time—which it must have—then the reflog for `master` includes the hash ID for commit `A`.  This reflog also includes the hash ID for commit `B`.  Once `master` no longer points directly to `C`, the `master` reflog will contain the hash id of `C` as well, and so on.

There's also a reflog for `HEAD` itself, recording the hash IDs that `HEAD` has pointed-to, either directly (detached) or indirectly (by being attached to a branch name).  So `git reflog HEAD` shows you those reflog entries, which allows you to find the actual hash ID for the commit you're looking for.

One downside with reflog entries is that they eventually *expire:* after 30 to 90 days, Git assumes you don't care any more.  That particular down-side won't apply here since the commit you are looking for is fresh.  The other (an other?) down-side is that the commits found in the reflog tend to all look alike, and there may be an awful lot of them, so it can be hard to find them in the noise.  One thing that helps is to note that they're kept in order: the `@{1}` entry is the old value from a moment ago, the `@{2}` entry is the one from before that, and so on.  So if you only recently switched, the one you want will be in the top few.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and enlightening answer! I did `git checkout *hash*` found in `git reflog` and I was able to continue my rebase. However, after I finished it with `git rebase --continue`, I am now in `HEAD detached from *hash*` state. How can I make my new commit after rebase to appear on my original branch `foo`?

Comment: Interesting: I had the impression the rebase should finish, but perhaps something took out part of the rebasing state. The last step of `git rebase` is that Git updates the original branch name, such as `foo`, to point to the current (detached-HEAD) commit and attaches `HEAD` to the now-updated name. So if your rebase is done (`git status` no longer says you are rebasing) but you have the desired tip commit, you can do this resetting yourself. The Git command that does it all in one command-line command is the rather peculiarly named `git checkout -B` (note uppercase B): `git checkout -B foo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{X}
```

where **X** is index commit **before** "o3820h HEAD@{Y}: checkout: moving from foo to bar"